# trying to fade out a top div on hover to reveal working links in text below using JQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, hover, fadein, fadeout

I need to fade a div (and image) to reveal a div underneath (text with clickable links) using jQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
</script>
```

Used the above code and all worked well, until I went to click the links. Seems the top hidden div is preventing me from doing so.

Tried the replaceWith function and that allowed me to click the links too - but couldn't get it to go back to showing original div when I moused out. Also, bossman wants the transition to be gradual - like a fade...

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Heath

Answer (score 0):

Okay - both of the following are working well enough in most browsers, but in IE, whenever I even move the mouse slightly, the div starts fading in and out - and also can build up a queue or a loop of the fadein/fadeout events:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#goingimg").hover(
        function () { $(".going").fadeOut("normal",0); }, 
        function () { $(".going").fadeTo("normal",1); }
    );       
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#goingimg").hoverIntent(function() {
        $(".gone").fadeOut("normal",0);
        $('#goingimg').hoverIntent(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); });
    }, function() {
        $(".gone").fadeTo("normal",1);
        $('#goingimg').hoverIntent(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); });
    });
});
```

I tried the suggested hoverIntent plugin, and the event.stopPropagation function. Still, in IE - things are just all screwy. Is there any way around this that anyone knows of?

Many thanks...